# How to count number of blanks in column?

Tags: excel, vba

I am using MS Excel 2016. Below VBA code throws an error

> Runtime Error 1004 App Defined or Obj Defined Error

I want to count the number of blanks in column AT and wherever there are blanks I want to replace it with "Nill". There are 29000 rows in the sheet.

```vb
Sub FillBlanks()
Dim cnt As Long
cnt=Range("AT:AT").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Count
On Error Resume Next
MsgBox cnt
End Sub
```

Comment: Change: `Range("AT:AT").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Count` for: `WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(Range("AT:AT"))`

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked, but I realized that there are spaces in columns which doesnt contain any Values. I want to trim the spaces and get Blanks count. Next I want to assign "Nill" string value to these rows in that column. Can you help me with this pls

Comment: I saw many people on Stackoverflow using SpecialCells. Has this been deprecated? Since it is not working for me.

Comment: this way is just shorter, so I'd go for that, even replace `WorksheetFunction` for `Application`. As per your other question, try the answer below if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub FillBlanks()
    Range("AT:AT").Replace What:="", Replacement:="NILL", LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. Any way I can check if blank column doesnt contain any Spaces so that I can first trim those spaces and then replace the values

Comment: Thanks. Yes you can do that.

Comment: Can we use ColumnName instead of Range?

Comment: Yes you can do that. Refer this: https://superuser.com/questions/875848/referencing-cell-only-by-column-name-in-excel-2010-vba